# gnome-keyring-daemon couldn't allocate secure memory

Tags: debian, gnome, memory, gnome-keyring, daemon

I run logcheck on my Debian Linux system to get alerted to unusual lines in my log files, and recently I saw the following in `/var/log/messages`:

```
gnome-keyring-daemon: couldn't allocate secure memory to keep passwords and or keys from being written to the disk
```

I don't know exactly what caused the message, just noticed it later in the logs. What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gnome-keyring-daemon is failing to allocate memory that cannot be swapped out (that's what it calls “secure memory”). The reason it tries to do that is that writing sensitive data (passwords or keys) to swap is a risk. It's only a risk against a specific threat, though: the threat that someone will steal your disk, but not your powered-on computer. It's irrelevant if you have no swap space or encrypt your swap space. It's also irrelevant if your computer is in a physically secure location. It is relevant if your computer is a laptop and you're worried about an unsophisticated thief, but unsophisticated thieves tend to care about your laptop's resale value and not your passwords (however, there is a burgeoning market for resale of corporate passwords). If you're worried about sophisticated thieves, you should be encrypting your confidential data and your swap space anyway.

Allocating memory that cannot be swapped out is done by the [`mlock`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mlock.html) system call, which locks a memory page at its present physical location. This requires privileges because otherwise an application could saturate the RAM. Under [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock), the appropriate privilege is the [`CAP_IPC_LOCK`](http://www.lids.org/lids-howto/node50.html) [capability](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/capabilities.7.html). Under [Solaris](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19109-01/tsolaris7/805-8069/6j7j9vo01/index.html), it's `PRIV_SYS_CONFIG`.

Under Linux, any process can lock a small amount of memory, determined by the `RLIMIT_MEMLOCK` limit. Under most shells, `ulimit -l` will show how much memory each unprivileged process may lock (in kB). If the limit is 0, check whether it's a hard limit (imposed by root, listed with `ulimit -Hl`) or a soft limit (self-imposed, listed by `ulimit -Sl`). You can raise the soft limit up to the hard limit with e.g. `ulimit -l 64`. To raise the hard limit, edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` (the syntax is documented in the file); this file is read when you log in.

TL,DR: it's a security feature, which you probably don't care about. Don't sweat it.

Answer (score 0):

I just got these messages on Ubuntu 18.04 and it turned out that for some reason `apparmor` stopped getting started on boot. Either starting `apparmor`, logging out and logging back in again fixes it temporarily, or turning `apparmor` on again on boot and rebooting also fixes it.

So if it was working and then stopped, you probably need to find out why this memory can no longer be allocated (so the above help, apparmor, selinux, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

I also got:

```
Oct 20 22:43:28 gnome-keyring-daemon[13543]: Gkm: using old keyring directory: /home/sergio/.gnome2/keyrings
Oct 20 22:43:28  gnome-keyring-daemon[13543]: Gkm: using old keyring directory: /home/sergio/.gnome2/keyrings
Oct 20 22:49:13  gnome-keyring-daemon[13543]: couldn't allocate secure memory to keep passwords and or keys from being written to the disk
```

The only solution that I found is begin a new keyring from scratch losing the passwords saved in previous keyring.
I removed .gnome2/keyrings and I lost all my passwords but gnome created a new directory with keyrings in .local/share/keyrings, and warnings disappear .

you can edit the passwords with command `seahorse`

I had a few passwords so I don't mind , but once I move .gnome2/keyrings directory I never get back my passwords. 
And solve the problem

Comment: downvoted because the solution causes loss of data when it actually isn't a big deal (see Gilles' answer). additionally, i suspect that this will fix a symptom, not the root cause.

Comment: no , you should migrate gnome-keyring, I just don't know how , and I warn that data will be lost .

Comment: Upvoted because this is the _only thing on the entire internet_ that I can find that tells me the location of the "new" keyring directory.

Comment: Addendum: "`mv .gnome2/keyrings .local/share/`", followed by logging out and back in, seems to be all you need to do to migrate.